# React Redux one-page app: handle an API 404 with full page render

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-redux

In a React one-page application using react-router to implement navigation, what's the best practice for rendering a full page error when encountering API errors requested when rendering a component in the page?

To be more specific, I understand react-router has a good method to implement a 404 error handler for URL routes that are simply not mapped, but when a route DOES match a mapped route with a dynamic portion of the URL (like an data-id) resulting in the rendering of a component that makes a request which responds in a 404 error, what is the best practice for replacing the entire react rendered view with an error view?

Example Scenario:

- Route = "/profile/person/:PersonId",
- Person ID 1234 does NOT exist in the backend.
- User visits "/profile/person/1234"
- The component for the profile/person/:PersonId route renders, and makes the request to get the profile data for person Id 1234, which returns with a 404, which really means the given URL is a 404, though not to react-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a suggestion as I don't really believe there is a defined best practice as you are asking.

```
ApiService.fetch(url).then(
  onSuccess(result) => { /* dispatch page fetch success */ },
  onError(result) => { /* dispatch page fetch error */ }
);
```

Then structure your app something like:

```
<App>
  { error ? <ErrorHandler /> : <PageHandler /> }
</App>
```

This structure would shortcut your page rendering on valid routes that encounter a server error and render error content instead.